# WCF Restful POST Return Error Message from Server to Client

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, post

i need an advice about how to return an error message caught on server to client. I am creating WCF Restfull service and able to returning an error message while using GET method. But hardly find the proper way to return error message from POST method.

**EDITED**

For @Abd:

I have tried using throw WebFaultException, like below code:

```
 try
                    {
                        newbudgetid = _service.Create(budgettrx);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        error_message = ex.Message;
                        MyCustomErrorDetail customerror = new MyCustomErrorDetail(
"Error", error_message);

                        throw new WebFaultException<MyCustomErrorDetail>(customerror, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

                    }
```

And this is the class definition:

```
public class MyCustomErrorDetail
    {
    public MyCustomErrorDetail(string errorInfo, string errorDetails)
        {
            ErrorInfo = errorInfo;
            ErrorDetails = errorDetails;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorInfo { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorDetails { get; private set; }
    }
```

On client code, how should i write the error output from server ?

```
 BudgetTransactionRequest bt = new BudgetTransactionRequest
                {
                    transaction_code = "7PRM007690 ",
                    category = "Expenses",
                    claim_status = "Presales ID",
                    amount = "320000.00000",
                    application_type = "Payment Request",
                    opportunity = "BSMD000586",
                    project = null,
                    request_date = new DateTime(2013, 03, 09),
                    request_status = "Validated",
                    owner = "nurul.wiiyanti",
                };




                WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
                proxy.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer serialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BudgetTransactionRequest));
                serialize.WriteObject(ms, bt);
                byte[] data = proxy.UploadData("http://10.10.64.19:8082/Service1.svc/CreateBudgetTransaction/", "POST", ms.ToArray());
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BudgetTransactionRequest));
```

Comment: I am also having same issue

Comment: Did you find solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ServiceResult class and use it for all Get and Post methods. In this class you can use properties such as Generic Result, HasException, ExceptionMessage etc.

Answer (score 0):

throw a WebFaultException(T errorDetail, HttpResponseCode code)

Here you set your response type to another object type, which makes sense, and also you set the ResponseCode that you want.

The errorDetail must be serializable

this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/21/error-handling-in-wcf-webhttp-services-with-webfaultexception.aspx) could be useful, or this [link](http://www.robbagby.com/rest/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/)

Comment: On client code, simply you can read the http Status Code "response.StatusCode" for status code and "response.Content.ReadAsString()" for content